# running vb.net application off a site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i designed a very simple vb.net application. i would like to my users to be able to access it through a website instead of locally. is this posible? how do i do it? does the webserver have to have special extensions? do i have to convert the program into a different format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 basic type of applications in .NET:

1. Console application
2. Windows Forms Application
3. ASP.NET application

If you want to run your application from a web server you need to create an ASP.NET application. The web server needs to have .NET installed and a [virtual directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx) setup for your application.

Comment: thakn you very much. what is the difference between console and winodws forms app?

Comment: Windows applications have user controls like buttons, text boxes, combo boxes, menus, etc... and use standard windows events to handle user actions while console applications can only take user input and output from/to the Console, command or a shell window.

Comment: darin - i've never used asp.net. is it sort of like vb.net?

Comment: @alex, VB.NET is a programming language, while ASP.NET is a web application written in one of the many CLS compliant languages. I would suggest you reading some introductory tutorial that could help you clarify the basics.